# How to scroll till an object is visible in a popup window?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to scroll till an object is visible in a popup window?

Selenium 3.141 with Java

1. Open a popup from base window
2. Switch to pop-up window
3. Now scroll down till some object is visible in pop-up(window scroller is available in pop-up window) and click

Expected Result: Scroll should happen till the object is visible and click

Actual Result: Switches to the pop-up window but fails to scroll

````
WebElement Element =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@search-item-predicate-value,'test_object')]"));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Element);

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.className("wux-scroller")), 500); //scrollTop works but scrollIntoView fails```
````

Comment: Have you checked this xpath '//*[contains(@search-item-predicate-value,'test_object')]' highlighting web element on popup manually?

Comment: Why do you need to it to be visible? Just click it or pull text or whatever it is that you need to do and move on.

Comment: you will find your answer within this . check the accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002523/how-can-i-scroll-mouse-in-specific-menu-in-main-window-in-java-selenium-webdrive/54007181#54007181

Comment: @Sreenivasulu yes, it highlights properly.

Comment: @SarojPurbey Thanks for suggestion. I tried as per comments but scroll didn't happen. In my case I need to first switch to container (grid view) and then scroll in grid view to find the element.

Comment: Alternatively, I tried with while loop. scroll 250px at once, check and click if element exist else continue loop till element found. This worked.

Comment: @JeffC Element is hidden in a window and it loads dynamically as and when user scrolls down. So scroll till element is visible and click on element is the action.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the item isn't loaded until the scroll is done.  (Dynamically loading content upon scroll action...) View source to confirm the item is actually there before scrolling.  If not, you need to scroll the window by pixels first.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you said you are switching to popup. i.e. it is not a driver scroll bar. It is a application level scroll bar. Hence, when you use javascriptexecutor, it won't scroll your popup.

To overcome this issue, follow below steps:
1) Switch to the popup window
2) Click on any of the element to make DOM active
3) Write an xpath for your DOM  as well
4) Use below code to scroll based on your requirement:

```
public static boolean scrollWebTable(String dom, String toSearch, String direction) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(dom)).click();
        int flag = 0;
        int count = 0;
        do {
            try {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(dom)).click();
                WebElement ele = Shared.driver.findElement(By.xpath(toSearch));
                flag = 1;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                switch (direction.toLowerCase()) {
                case "right":
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(dom)).sendKeys(Keys.RIGHT);
                    break;
                case "left":
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(dom)).sendKeys(Keys.LEFT);
                    break;
                case "down":
                default:
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(dom)).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
                    break;
                case "up":
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(dom)).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_UP);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while ((flag == 0) || ((++count) == 250));
        return (flag == 1);
    }
```

call this method from your POM class by passing DOM and elementToSearch xpath and in which direction you want to scroll either UP or DOWN or RIGHT or LEFT.
Here, while loop will be executed (i.e. it will scroll) the page until your expected element to be displayed.

Note: This code will work only when your popup will be scrolled when your keyboard arrow keys..